# How to get absolute paths of nodes found using relative xpaths in R?

Tags: r, xml, xpath

Giving a complicated website parsed as HTML:

```
library("XML")
doc<-htmlParse("Webpage.html")
xpath<-"//par" #relative path
```

I can, for example, find all the nodes which match the relative path:

```
data<-xpathSApply(doc,xpath)
```

but how can I find the absolute paths to these nodes?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `xmlAncestors` with option `fun=xmlName` to get the full path.

```
doc <- htmlParse("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42031842")
summary(doc)
xpathSApply(doc, "//h3", xmlValue)

xpathSApply(doc, "//h3", function(y) paste(unlist( xmlAncestors(y, fun=xmlName)), collapse="/")) 
[1] "html/body/div/div/div/div/div/h3"                     
[2] "html/body/div/div/div/div/div/h3"                     
[3] "html/body/div/div/div/div/div/h3"                     
[4] "html/body/div/div/div/div/div/form/div/div/div/div/h3"
[5] "html/body/div/div/div/div/div/form/div/div/div/div/h3"
[6] "html/body/div/div/div/div/div/form/div/noscript/h3"   

xpathSApply(doc, "/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/form/div/noscript/h3", xmlValue)
[1] "Post as a guest"
```